# Elasticsearch is installed in my server and i'm running docker-compse up and getting error "ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused"

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch

i'm running docker-compse up and getting error with elasticsearch   "ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused"
i changed elasticsearch.yml and i changes to networkhost 0.0.0.0
still i'm same error

Here it goes:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/_alias [status:N/A request:0.000s]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
        (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
        raise err
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
        sock.connect(sa)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 166, in perform_request
        response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=request_headers, **kw)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
        _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 333, in increment
        raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
        conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
        self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
        self.connect()
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 166, in connect
        conn = self._new_conn()
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
        self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6471e8f588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
    GET http://localhost:9200/_alias [status:N/A request:0.000s]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
        (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
        raise err
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
        sock.connect(sa)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 166, in perform_request
        response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=request_headers, **kw)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
        _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 333, in increment
        raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
        conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
        self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
        self.connect()
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 166, in connect
        conn = self._new_conn()
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
        self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6471e8f630>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
    GET http://localhost:9200/_alias [status:N/A request:0.000s]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
        (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
        raise err
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
        sock.connect(sa)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 166, in perform_request
        response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=request_headers, **kw)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
        _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 333, in increment
        raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
        conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
        self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
        self.connect()
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 166, in connect
        conn = self._new_conn()
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
        self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6471e8f710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
    GET http://localhost:9200/_alias [status:N/A request:0.000s]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
        (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
        raise err
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
        sock.connect(sa)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 166, in perform_request
        response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=request_headers, **kw)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
        _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 333, in increment
        raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
        conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
        self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
        self.connect()
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 166, in connect
        conn = self._new_conn()
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
        self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6471e290f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
        (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
        raise err
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
        sock.connect(sa)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 166, in perform_request
        response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=request_headers, **kw)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
        _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 333, in increment
        raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
        conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
        self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
        self.connect()
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 166, in connect
        conn = self._new_conn()
      File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
        self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6471e290f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Can you share you docker-compose yml file?